# ways of conditionally writing html

Tags: javascript, html

I want to detect if the browser supports different functions:

```
   var useWrappedLayout = (document.getElementById != undefined);
```

I have to support quite old devices, thats why I check for getElementById.

Depending on if `useWrappedLayout` is true or not, I want the page to have some HTML-Elements or not.

For keeping things simple and to have an example, lets say I only want to have

```
 <p>Test</p>
```

between

```
 <b>A</b><i>C</i>
```

if `useWrappedLayout` is `true`.

What methods do I have? Only `innerHTML`?

Comment: *What methods do I have? Only innerHTML?* Doesn't that depend on the browsers you want to support? I'd check that first.

Comment: If the reason for you needing to ask this question is complications due to needing to support "quite old devices", I think you need to give us some examples of such devices you'll need to support so we have an idea of what the lowest common denominator is.

Comment: *quite old devices*...[how old?](http://uhaweb.hartford.edu/klotz/firstcellphone1.jpg)

Comment: What browser are we talking about? getElementById has been supported for a very long time. If you give us an example of what you are trying to target it could make it easier to understand what you want to do.

Comment: I know getElementByID is not supported, for example in the IE shipped with PocketPC 4.20 (that is some kind, but not exactly the same one as, IE5.5). But is that REALLY related to my question? I wanted to ask for ways of omitting HTML-Markup. `innerHTML` is one, which else do you know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building the HTML dynamically using javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var useWrappedLayout = (document.getElementById != undefined);
    document.write("<b>A</b>" + ((useWrappedLayout) ? "<p>Test</p>" : "") + "<i>C</i>");
</script>
```

Comment: That seems to be exactly what I wanted (: Thank you very much! Does document.write, write always right after the script-tag?

Comment: document.write will override the contents of the document. See here for the warning. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_howto.asp